# Spacers for pins of long-pinned female headers

Tags: header, pin-headers

Do they sell just the plastic part of board spacers for single-row pin headers?

If I want to use a [long-pinned female header](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/118231/female-rectangular-headers-with-long-pins-pass-through-style) to effectively make a pass-through header (PCB top-side: female header, PCB bottom-side: male header), but I want to raise the PCB slightly. Is the plastic portion of board spacers sold without pins?

Effectively, I'd like to put the following on top of a board

[image: Long-pinned female header]

and then add the plastic portion of the following on the pins below the board:

[image: Board spacers]

I can't change the height of what the pins connect to — I am interfacing to something already set in stone.

Comment: you can push the pins out of the plastic carrier ... why do you need the spacer? ... normally, there would not be one

Comment: @jsotola : It varies. In case I want the board raised higher than the mating connector allows, in case the pins are too long for the receiving connector and I don't want to clip the tapered pin ends off, etcetera : j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they do not sell those spacers separately :( You can always push out the pins and get a spacer that way. Buy the cheapest tin plated pins, since you'd be discarding them.

These spacers may not work well for your application. The pins that come inserted into the spacers are square. The pins of the  long pinned female headers are usually rectangular in cross-section, and don't necessarily share any dimensions with the square pins - so they won't be retained very well by the spacers.